# JAVA Equals Alternative

Tags: java, operators

I was just wondering if there was an alternative to the following operator:

```
if (f == 0){
    System.out.print("");
} else if (i %2 == 1){
    System.out.print("; ");
}
```

To be clearer, I would like an alternative way of writing the if statement's "==" and the else if statement's `%2 == 1`.

Thanks.

Comment: And the motivation is?

Comment: why did you wonder? ;)

Comment: Your question is not very clear - what do you want to replace? You have two variables: `f` and `i` - is that a typo?

Comment: Switch Case is an alternative

Comment: you can use `if(! f != 0 )`... joking :P what's the problem with `==`?

Comment: I am just curious. Especially with the modulo.

Comment: Which operator are you referring to? The == or the modulo? What are f and i?

Comment: But what do you want to replace? The condition? the `==` operator?

Comment: @JohnSmith Stackoverflow is for [practical problems](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) Do you have any problems with equality operator? Does it introduce some limitations?

Comment: hmm, this question isn't a very practical one. I'll ask for it to be removed. It was just a curiosity one, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.print(f!=0 && i%2==1 ? "; " : "");`

Instead of the modulo you can flag out all bits of i except the last one by a bitwise and.

The alternative to `i%2` is `i&1`.

Comment: That's not exactly the same. You always print something, the OP only prints if `f` equals 0 or if `i%2` equals 1

Comment: this is not called alternative. this is called something different.

Comment: @Kent I used "alternative" in a sense explained in [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alternative). I see that "alternative" implies "white box equivalence" in this case. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In java 7 you can compare like this

```
int result = Integer.compare(f, 10);
```

Description of the method

```
public static int compare(int x,
          int y)

Compares two int values numerically. The value returned is identical to what would be returned by:

    Integer.valueOf(x).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(y))


Parameters:
    x - the first int to compare
    y - the second int to compare
Returns:
    the value 0 if x == y; a value less than 0 if x < y; and a value greater than 0 if x > y
Since: 1.7
```

Taken from official document

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29

and In java 6

```
int result = Double.compare(f, 10);
```

Description of the method

```
 compare

public static int compare(double d1,
                          double d2)

    Compares the two specified double values. The sign of the integer value returned is the same as that of the integer that would be returned by the call:

        new Double(d1).compareTo(new Double(d2))


    Parameters:
        d1 - the first double to compare
        d2 - the second double to compare 
    Returns:
        the value 0 if d1 is numerically equal to d2; a value less than 0 if d1 is numerically less than d2; and a value greater than 0 if d1 is numerically greater than d2.
    Since:
        1.4
```

Taken fropm official docs

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare%28double,%20double%29

**you can use any of the approach according to your requirements**

**I have tested both of them**

**see my tested solution
for java 6 http://ideone.com/56dm1T
for java 7 http://ideone.com/mEjt6W**

Comment: But for equality you'll have to compare the returned `int` with `0`. So this doesn't avoid the use of `==`.

Comment: @NishantShreshth Ya that remains there but anyways problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Equals operator `==` compares references in the case of objects and actual values in the case of primitive types.

A scenario where this operator can be replaced with `equals(Object obj)` is when the wrapper objects of primitive types are used.

So, if there are two `int`, `a` and `b`, and you obtain their wrappers with:

```
Integer objA = Integer.valueOf(a);
Integer objB = Integer.valueOf(b);
```

`a == b` gives the same result as `objA.equals(objB)`.